# Text Area For - non re-sizable

Tags: css, browser, textarea, resizable

I have the follwing mark-up in my cshtml file.  However the textbox area has a dragable corner in the bottom left corner that when dragged re-sizes the text area and affects all other text boxes/drop downs etc on the page.

```
            <td class="label">
                Notes :
            </td>
            <td class="value" rowspan="3">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { cols = "40%", style = "width:250px;", @maxlength = "255" })
            </td>
```

Is there anything I can add to disable the textareafor from being resizeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in the css `resize:none`:

use :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { cols = "40%", style = "width:250px;resize:none", @maxlength = "255" })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C# or ASP.net problem.

In fact it is no problem at all, it is a feature of the browser you are using.

You should be able to get rid of it with using the CSS3 property `resize` like;

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Or, if need only vertical resize:

```
textarea {
     resize: vertical;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your browser does this. It enhances the user experience. Why do you want to disable it?

You can however do this by [applying some CSS](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0jzrfB7m3N4):

```
textarea { 
    resize: none; 
}
```